# Suppose $Z\to Y$ is a morphism of schemes, and $f(z)$ is contained in an open affine of $V\subset Y$. Do the specializations of $z$ also lie in $V$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I am trying to prove Corollary 4.6(f) of Hartshorne Chapter 2.4 using the valuative criterion for separated morphisms:

> Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism between Noetherian schemes, and suppose there is an open cover $\{ V_i \}$ of $Y$ such that $f^{-1}(V_i)\to V_i$ is separated for each $i$. Show that $f$ is separated.

Suppose we have a commutative diagram of the form in the valuative criterion, with morphisms $\phi,\psi:\operatorname{Spec}R\to X$, where $R$ is a valuation ring. Let $x_1$ is the point corresponding to the zero ideal in $R$, and $x_0$ the point corresponding to the maximal ideal, where we have $x_0\in\overline{\{x_1\}}$ is a specialization. Suppose $V\subset Y$ is an open affine - is it true that if $f(x_1)\in V$, then $f(x_0)\in V$? If it were true, then the proposition would follow immediately by just considering any of the open subsets in the cover that contain the image of $x_1$, and I have seen a source do this to prove it, but I do not know how or why this is true.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have this backwards? Think about $\operatorname{Spec} k[t]_{(t)}\to \operatorname{Spec} k[t]$ in the obvious manner. Then the open affine $D(t)$ contains the image of the generic point, but does not contain the image of the closed point.

Comment: You're right, it was a 50/50 chance - is the opposite then true - do the generizations lie in the same affine?

Comment: If you take the projective line $P^1$ then the complement of any point is an affine scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I write generalization instead of generization because I like it better.)

You have this backwards - the appropriate statement is that if $x$ lies in an open set $U$, then every generalization of $x$ lies in $U$ as well. The reason is just point set topology: if $y$ is a generalization of $x$ not lying in $U$, then $U^c$ is a closed set containing $y$ not containing $x$, so $x\notin\overline{\{y\}}$ by the definition of the closure as the smallest closed set containing $y$. This contradicts the definition of generalization, so $y$ must be in $U$.

Comment: Once it was revealed that I got it the wrong way round it was easy, but have the green check!

Comment: Why does this prove the result? If $Y$ can be covered by opens $V_1$ and $V_2$ each containing the image of the generic point, $x_1$, why can't there be two distinct extensions $f_i$ factoring through $V_i$ respectively?

Comment: @StevenMai start with the standard valuative diagram and suppose the closed point of $\operatorname{Spec} R$ lands in $V_i$. Then the generic point must also land in $V_i$, and hence $\operatorname{Spec} K$ must land in $f^{-1}(V_i)$ as well. Any extension must also have the closed point land in $f^{-1}(V_i)$ by commutativity of the diagram (remember, the image of the closed point in $X$ must land in $f^{-1}(V_i)$ as the closed point lands in $V_i$), so the valuative criteria applied to $f^{-1}(V_i)\to V_i$ shows that there's at most one extension and we win.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for the explanation